# Apache Spark spark.read not working as intended

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, ibm-cloud, apache-spark-ml

I am learning IBM Apache Spark. I am using HMP dataset. I followed the instructions from a tutorial but the code is not working as intended. Here is me code:

```
!git clone https://github.com/wchill/HMP_Dataset

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("x",IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("y",IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("z",IntegerType(), True)
])

import os
file_list = os.listdir("HMP_Dataset")
file_list_filtered = [file for file in file_list if "_" in file]
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
for cat in file_list_filtered:
    data_files = os.listdir("HMP_Dataset/" + cat)

    for data_file in data_files:
        print(data_file)

        temp_df = spark.read.option("header","false").option( "delimeter" , " ").csv("HMP_Dataset/" + cat + "/" + data_file, schema=schema)

        temp_df = temp_df.withColumn("class",lit(cat))
        temp_df = temp_df.withColumn("source",lit(data_file))

        if df is None:
            df = temp_df
        else:
            df = df.union(temp_df)
```

The schema of x,y,z is remaining null on using the df.show() method. Here is the output:

```
+----+----+----+-----------+--------------------+
|   x|   y|   z|      class|              source|
+----+----+----+-----------+--------------------+
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
|null|null|null|Brush_teeth|Accelerometer-201...|
+----+----+----+-----------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The x, y, z columns must have numbers. What am I doing wrong? I used the exact code showed in the tutorial video. I am using the IBM Watson Studio for running the program. Link to tutorial https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-machine-learning-signal-processing/lecture/8cfiW/introduction-to-sparkml

Comment: why am I getting downvoted? what is wrong with question? atleast suggest before doing that

Comment: > I followed the instructions from a tutorial 
What tutorial, can you provide the URL?

Comment: @PowellQuiring here https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-machine-learning-signal-processing/lecture/8cfiW/introduction-to-sparkml

Comment: What is the expected output or what isn't working?  It is unclear what the problem is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have typo in the option where you specified "delimeter" vs correct option to pass is "delimiter"

```
temp_df = spark.read.option("header","false").option( "delimeter" , " ").csv("HMP_Dataset/" + cat + "/" + data_file, schema=schema)
```

Correct:-

```
temp_df = spark.read.option("header","false").option( "delimiter" , " ").csv("HMP_Dataset/" + cat + "/" + data_file, schema=schema)
```

You can also alternatively use "sep" for seperator.
For more reference, refer spark-csv here or in spark documentation:- 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv